# Multi split together with brackets

Tags: java

I have a string and I want to splits these signs .,:[]

I like to know how to split multiple delimiters together with the brackets?

`String  splitme = "mom.girl, dad:boy [ girl, aunt ] granny";`

I know how to do it without a [ `"brackets"` if that what's it called.
`splitme.split("[.,:]"`);

Comment: Just to be sure: What result were you expecting from your example string?

Comment: This is not `java` question, but `regular expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.split(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) use regular expression, `[` and `]` are both reserved character. You just need to escape the character that are "reserved".

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "ab.cd;ef[gi]ij,kl";
    for(String a : s.split("[.,;\\[\\]]")){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
ab
cd
ef
gi
ij
kl
```